# Multirow multicolumn in overleaf

Tags: latex, overleaf, multirow

I want to make a table like this in overleaf using multi row and column. Unable to figure out how to use these commands

[image: example table with cells taking up multiple columns]

Comment: Use a column specification like `p{2cm}|p{1cm}|c|c|{5cm}` and see how that comes out. For the first column you can use `\multirow` where applicable.

Comment: This question should be posted in tex.stackexchange (https://tex.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `tabularx` package, then latex will automatically adapt your column widths to the available space:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{geometry}

\begin{document}


\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{p{2cm}p{1.5cm}p{1.5cm}p{1.5cm}X}
\toprule
& Largest problem solved & Computer & Time & Remarks\\
\midrule
Dynamic programming (Held and Karp) & 13 & 7090 & 0.98 &
\vspace*{-\baselineskip}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Storage limitations prevented the solution of larger problems
\item Required computer time is deterministic
\end{enumerate}\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with better spacing.
I also used a smaller font (`footnotesize`) for the table.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}

% See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/6454/113546
\newcommand\compress{\csname @minipagetrue\endcsname}
\newenvironment{smallenum}{\begin{enumerate}[(1), left=0pt, nosep]\compress}{\end{enumerate}}
\newcolumntype{q}[1]{>{\centering}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{r}[1]{>{\centering}m{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{footnotesize}\noindent
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}p{3cm} q{8mm} q{8mm} q{6mm} X}
    \toprule
    & \multicolumn{1}{r{8mm}}{Largest problem solved} & \multicolumn{1}{r{8mm}}{Com\-puter} & \multicolumn{1}{r{6mm}}{Time (min)} & 
    \multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}m{5cm}}{Remarks} \\
    \midrule Dynamic programming (Held and Karp) & 13 & 7090 & 0.98 &
    \begin{smallenum}
    \item  Storage limitations prevented the solution of larger problems
    \item Required computer time is deterministic
    \end{smallenum} \\
    Branch-and-Bound (Little, et al) & 40 & 7090 & 8.37 &
    \begin{smallenum}
      \item Time reported is the expected time and one might experience large deviations for a particular problem.
      \item Time reported refers to randomly selected, asymmetric $c_{ij}$. Considerable difficulty reported for Euclidean problems.
    \end{smallenum}\\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabularx}
\end{footnotesize}

\end{document}
```

[image]